# How can I update TABLE1 rows when I change some TABLE2 rows in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am building a soccer management tool where the league's admin can update the score of every match in the MATCHES TABLE. At the same time I want to update the TEAMS TABLE columns.

For instance if the match is DALLAS vs PHOENIX, and the score was DALLAS 2 - PHOENIX 3, I want to update that match in the MATCH TABLE (I know how to tho this) but at the same time I want to update the points of those two teams based on the result we just updated.

Is there a way to do that in POSTGRESQL?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please take a few minuets and review [ask]. Post your table definitions (actual ddl) and sample data, as text - **no images**, and the expected results of that data. Additionally, it would bee beneficial to define what you mean by points. There are most likely several ways to accomplish what you want. But none with the above information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for triggers. What is a Database trigger? A database trigger is a special stored procedure that is run when specific actions occur within a database. Most triggers are defined to run when changes are made to a table’s data. Triggers can be defined to run after (or before) INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE table records. Triggers use two special database objects, `INSERTED` and `DELETED`, to access rows affected by the database actions.

When table record is inserted – Use the `INSERTED` table to determine which rows were added to the table.

When table record is deleted – Use the `DELETED` table to see which rows were removed from the table.

When table record is updated – Use the `INSERTED` table to inspect the new or updated values and the `DELETED` table to see the values prior to update.

In PostgreSQL `INSERTED` trigger object is called `NEW` and `DELETED` object is called `OLD`

For example:
We have two tables, `user_group` and `user_detail`. I would like to insert 12 records into table `user_detail` when inserting data to table `user_group`

```
CREATE TABLE examples.user_group (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    group_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE examples.user_detail (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    "month" int2 NOT NULL
);


-- create trigger function for inserting 12 records into user_detail table 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION examples.f_user_group_after_insert()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
    p_user_id integer;
begin
    p_user_id := new.user_id;  -- new is a system table (trigger objects), which return inserted new records for user_group tables 
 
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 1);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 2);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 3);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 4);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 5);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 6);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 7);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 8);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 9);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 10);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 11);
    insert into examples.user_detail (user_id, month) values (p_user_id, 12);
 
    return new;
end;
$function$
;


-- join trigger function to user_group table, when will be run after insert
create trigger user_group_after_insert 
after insert
on
    examples.user_group for each row execute function examples.f_user_group_after_insert();
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I was looking for.